# What to use in context: "surely" or "sure"

Tags: grammaticality

Which expression is correct:

> I sure hope so.
>   I surely hope so.

I would say the second one. However, the first one seems to be used more often.

Or are they both correct?

Comment: Ans: http://archive.is/nqDyU#selection-1657.0-1889.1

Answer (score 5):

> "I sure hope so"

is a colloquial American usage.

Native British speakers would be highly unlikely to say this unless they were imitating American speech:

> "I surely hope so", "I certainly hope so"

and other, similar constructions are what you could expect to hear in Britain.

Comment: Surely <"*Going home?*" "*Sure.*">'s British too?

Answer (score 0):

"Surely" is traditional, formal, correct. "Sure" is colloquial, informal, common, and also correct (at least it is in America.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, beyond that "Americsn" or "British" never ending debate, basic rules do exsist in the common English Language.
"Surely" is an adverb and "hot" is an adjective. Adverbs modify adjectives.
"Sure" is an adjective and modifies nouns and pronouns; since this is not the case here "surely" is thus correct AT ALL TIMES, grammatically.